# Avoid to create a new window in sql mode

Tags: emacsclient, sql

I use a monitor and a laptop screen as my multimonitor setup.

Unfortunately the monitor and the laptop differs in resolution.
So I use 2 frames, one frame on the monitor and one frame on the laptop screen.

Both frames are connected to one Emacs instance.

**MONITOR**:
I will call the frame that's opened on monitor as `frame 1`.
In the `frame 1` on the monitor, I have a buffer opened with the default SQL-mode that's shipped with Emacs.

**LAPTOP**:
On the laptop screen, there is a SQL-process being displayed in the Emacs `frame 2`.

**SITUATION**:
In the `frame 1`, in the buffer with SQL-mode, I call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sql-send-region` to send a SQL-statement to the SQL-process.

I see the result on the laptop screen in `frame 2`. But in the meanwhile, the SQL-mode propably have detected there is no window in the Emacs `frame 1`, so Emacs opens a new window with the same buffer of the SQL-process.

As the result, there are two windows on two screens, viewing the same buffer (the SQL-process).

I would prevent that the SQL-mode opens a new window when sending a SQL-statement to the SQL-process. How could I 'tell' Emacs to prevent that?

**EDIT** as answered below, this question is solved by now. See the second option from the user `bmag`.

Comment: Please consider mentioning `sql-send-region` or `sql-mode` in your question title. I'd edit it myself, but ambiguous titles are a common feature of your questions. If you name them better, we can find them easier. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't have the idea opening new windows is specific for sql-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, the problem is that Emacs doesn't reuse the window from `frame 2` when `frame 1` is the selected frame. As per [Window-Choice page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html) in the manual, you can set `pop-up-frames` to `t`:

```lisp
(setq pop-up-frames t)
```

Setting `pop-up-frames` to `t` will make Emacs consider windows on other frames whenever it needs to display a buffer. If you want Emacs to reuse windows from another frame only for SQL's process buffer, you need to add an entry to `display-buffer-alist`:

```lisp
(push '("<buffer-name>" nil . ((reusable-frames . t))) display-buffer-alist)
```

Where `<buffer-name>` should be replaced with the name of SQL's process buffer. The documentation of `display-buffer-alist` and `display-buffer` (via `C-h v` and `C-h f`) explains them in great detail. You can [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#Choosing-Window) [related](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html#Choosing-Window-Options) [pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html#Display-Action-Functions) from the Elisp manual to learn more.

Note that I am assuming `sql-mode` uses `pop-to-buffer` or similar to switch to SQL's process buffer. If it uses `switch-to-buffer` or `split-window` (it shouldn't), then my answer isn't likely to work.

Comment: The second option with pushing the buffer-name (which is `*SQL*`) to reusable frames, solved my question. I really appreciate you for that answer. Now I have a good base to figure out further how I could switch to the original frame afterwards. 
Thanks for the link about `display-action`. Emacs is so awesome, but it's sometimes too large to handle and so difficult to find your way around in all the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, as I don't use `sql-mode`:

```el
(defun nadvice/sql-send-string (old-fun &rest args)
  (cl-letf* (((old-display-buffer (symbol-function #'display-buffer))
              ((symbol-function #'display-buffer)
               (lambda (buffer-or-name &rest iargs)
                 (unless (get-buffer-window-list buffer-or-name)
                   (apply old-display-buffer buffer-or-name iargs))))))
    (apply old-fun args)))

(advice-add 'sql-send-string :around #'nadvice/sql-send-string)
```

Comment: As you already said, it's untested. I ran into an error after applying your function: `let*: Invalid function: (symbol-function (function display-buffer))`.

Comment: Hm... that is strange. I've corrected one typo in the code, but I doubt that's what was causing your issue.