# How do I encourage Emacs to follow the output of the SQL-buffer?

Tags: sql-mode

[This issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/avoid-opening-a-new-window-in-sq-mode) might be related.

I have a `SQL` process viewed in a buffer in a frame.

When I send SQL-statements from another window in frame to the SQL-process in the another frame, I have to scroll my SQL buffer to see the details of output. When I'm in an another buffer,  emacs stops "following" the SQL buffer, i.e., scrolling to automatically display new output.

Any idea how I can "reattach" or encourage Emacs to follow the SQL buffer?

**UPDATE:** As noted in the replies below, you can set up Emacs to follow the tail of the output again, with to set up the point to the end of the buffer with <kbd>M-></kbd>

Comment: Just put point at the end again...

Comment: @wasamasa what do you mean? I couldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Put the cursor at the end of the buffer, like with `M->`.  Any further scrolling should keep it at the end.

Comment: The following link contains some ideas that can be borrowed to create a solution to this answer -- **In emacs, can I set up the *Messages* buffer so that it tails?** -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682033/in-emacs-can-i-set-up-the-messages-buffer-so-that-it-tails

Comment: @wasamasa thanks for your reply! Could you add it as answer, so I can mark it as the correct answer, in order to be findable for other users?

Comment: @lawlist thanks for the link, it's appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make buffers scroll along with newly appended contents, position point at their end (like with `M->`).